Gradient inbound
I’m looking for a way to make the gradient start from the center if an object and end close to it’s surface. No problem to make it with a sphere, but how is it possible to apply for other shapes of distinctive faces like cube or just random blob mesh?
Guess there should be some math nodes using object normals, but my knowledge is not enough here.

